# Windows 8: Play a full screen game in windowed mode

Tags: windows-8, resolution

I am playing a (lesser known) game on Windows 8 since yesterday, however I cannot alt-tab out of the game when it is in fullscreen, it seems like it is not fixable as of now. So the only solution if I want to be able to alt-tab, is to use windowed mode.

Details:

- Full HD resolution, 1920 x 1080
- Windows 8 64-bit

The game allows me to set a custom resolution for windowed mode. So I would like to know the following things:

- The height of the top bar of a windowed application in Windows 8.
- The height of the taskbar in Windows 8.

I prefer to rely on given values rather than (my own) measurements.

I hope anyone has encountered this before and can give me the correct resolution.

Comment: These dimensions differ from system to system. There are API calls to determine them, if you are a programmer. That's precisely to avoid them from using given values. Won't help you here, though.

Comment: @MSalters Just a player of the game in question. I could myself write some Java program (to show the values) though if you could give some hints on to where you find those values, as I don't know their 'official' names.

Comment: Native API: [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx)